# WPF Textblock Updates from Bound Property in ViewModel Partially

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous, mvvm

I have a rather strange behavior from my code. I designed a Textblock to update with a number that represents the percentage progress from two `for` loop.

50% percent of the progress is reported by `IProgress` reporter from one loop, then the remaining 50% is reported from the second loop using the same `IProgress` reporter.

The code for the loops is something like this:

```
public List<List<string[]>> PopulateSourceList(Sources refSources, CancellationToken cancellationToken=default, ObservableCollectionEx<ISourceModel> NormalReferenceSourceItems = null, ObservableCollectionEx<ISourceModel> CourtCaseSourceItems = null, IProgress <Interfaces.Model.ProgressReport> sourceUpdateProgressReporting = null)
{
    Sources sources = refSources;
    int sourcesCount = sources.Count;
    List<NormalReferenceSourceModel> normalRefSources = new List<NormalReferenceSourceModel>();
    List<CourtCaseSourceModel> courtRefSources = new List<CourtCaseSourceModel>();

    for (int s = 1; s <= sourcesCount; s++)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        Source source = sources[s];
        string cited = source?.Cited == true ? "YES" : "NO";
        string title;
        string year;
        try
        {
            title = source.Field["Title"];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            title = string.Empty;
        }
        try
        {
            year = source.Field["Year"];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            year = string.Empty;
        }
        string[] results = new string[] { authorBuilder.ToString(), title, cited, tag, year };
        if (caseType.Equals("case"))
        {
            courtRefSources?.Add(new CourtCaseSourceModel(authorBuilder.ToString(), title, cited, tag, year));
            cases.Add(results);
        }
        else
        {
            normalRefSources?.Add(new NormalReferenceSourceModel(authorBuilder.ToString(), title, cited, tag, year));
            items.Add(results);
        }
        int percentageP = (int)(Math.Round(s/(double)sourcesCount, 2) * 50);
        sourceUpdateProgressReporting.Report(new ProgressReport("SourcesExtraction", percentageP, 100));
    }

    if(NormalReferenceSourceItems != null)
    {
        normalRefSources.Sort();
        int articlesSourceCount = normalRefSources.Count;
        for (int a = 0; a < articlesSourceCount; a++)
        {
            NormalReferenceSourceItems.Add(normalRefSources[a]);
            int cuurentPercentage = 50 + (int)(Math.Round(a / (double)articlesSourceCount, 2) * 50);
            sourceUpdateProgressReporting.Report(new ProgressReport("SourcesExtraction", cuurentPercentage, 100));
        }
        sourceUpdateProgressReporting.Report(new Interfaces.Model.ProgressReport("Done", 100, 100));
    }
}
```

For every report the `IProgress` reporter sends, an `EventHandler` is invoked. The WPF ViewModel is subscribed to the event and the property bound to the `TextBlock`'s `Text` is updated in the event listener. The first half (50%) of the report is captured and updated in the View successfully, but then it stops there and never updates the remaining 50%.

The method in the ViewModel that listens to the event is here:

```
private void OpenDocumentModel_SourceUpdateProgressChangedEvent(object sender, Interfaces.Helpers.SourceUpdateProgressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ReportProgress) return;
    if (!e.ProgressState.Equals("Done"))
    {
        UpdateProgress = $"{(int)e.Value}%";
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateProgress = $"{(int)e.Value}%";
        UpdateProgress = string.Empty;
        ReportProgress = false;
        CenitxVisibility = "Visible";
        ProgressBarVisibility = "Collapsed";
    }
}
```

`UpdatePrgress` is the property bound to the TextBlock.

The property gets updated successfully as investigated from its `setter` but only the first 50% is reflected on the `TextBlock` itself When the final progress report is sent however. But strangely again, the final call that sets the `UpdateProgress` property to `string.empty` is reflected by the TextBlock and the View finally updates successfully.

The last call is the one that carries "Done" as the progress state and is triggered by:

```
sourceUpdateProgressReporting.Report(new Interfaces.Model.ProgressReport("Done", 100, 100));
```

Does anyone has any hint at all about why this is happening?

Comment: Does it stop at `if(NormalReferenceSourceItems != null)`?

Comment: yes it dos. but `NormalReferenceSourceItems` is almost never equals to `null`.

Comment: Almost never? Is `PopulateSourceList` executed on a background thread? Did you debug to determine whether `sourceUpdateProgressReporting.Report(new Interfaces.Model.ProgressReport("Done", 100, 100))`is actually called when you expect?

Comment: Yes! I've debugged to check that it was called as expected at the end of the looping. That is the only time that `e.ProgressState.Equals("Done")` is true. `PopulateSourceList` is executed on a background thread yes. But since all the loops are in the same method and the first half is returned successfully, I didn't think it's because of the thread difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to me it seems like this is just because the program runs "too fast".

I do not have a lot of details, so it would help if you could tell us how many items
are usually inside `Sources` and `NormalReferenceSourceItems`

My theory is that your loop of

```
for (int a = 0; a < articlesSourceCount; a++)
{
     NormalReferenceSourceItems.Add(normalRefSources[a]);
     int cuurentPercentage = 50 + (int)(Math.Round(a / (double)articlesSourceCount, 2) * 50);
     sourceUpdateProgressReporting.Report(new ProgressReport("SourcesExtraction", cuurentPercentage, 100));
}
```

finishes before you have any time to take notice of changes in the textbox.
Now if you already tried this with delays or similar things Id would be helpfull to know.
The fact that you are able to see the final change of `string.empty` would be because its the last, and therefore, permanent change.

This could all be wrong, but in that case id appreciate it if you were to give us a overview of the kind/size of data that passes into the method in your test runs.

Comment: Yes, i suspected the "too fast" possiblity too and tried to use a delay of 3 sec, yet the same behaviour is observed. The number of items in the two loops are mostly the same and on the average around 30-0. Each cycle of the first loop takes longer as there is some data extraction and `StringBuilder` "building" that is done before it is completed. But the delay I tested the secon loop with should have taken care of the difference. As a temporary measure to keep my app working, I just remove the report per cycle in the second loop and report full 100% in the first loop.

Comment: When you say they average around 30-0 what do exactly mean by that? Do you mean that they range from 30 to 0 or that one usually holds 30 and the other 0? Id also like to know a bit more about NormalReferenceSourceItems and its uses etc

Comment: so sorry, I mean 30-40.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I know its a stretch, but could you give me some more points about `NormalReferenceSourceItems` and the like? I just want to understand what the individual parts are, so I can have a better picture of the situation. Like you have both NormalReferenceSourceItems and normalRefSources. What are they?

Comment: `NormalReferenceSourceItems` is an `ObservableCollection`. It does not have a method for sorting itself. So to update the collection at any point, the items must first be gathered into a `List<NormalReferenceSourceModel>` list, sort the list and then replace everything inside the corresponding `ObservableCollection`. The inabilty of the `ObservableCollection` to sort itself is the reason my code has to go through all this trouble. And I need to use it because there are changes on the items in the collection that must be observed on the UI as they happen.

Comment: Ok something else that interests me, is the purpose of caseType. Like under what conditions is it "case". And what does your ProgressReport class look like? And Id also like to see the line where you call this Method

Comment: Also looking at some of your previous questions, I saw a bit of code for a ObservableCollectionEx. Is this similr to the one you are using in this Project?

Comment: That is the one I am using. It's just an extension of the normal `ObservableCollection` with just a slight modification. In any case, it isn't important in the UI update of concern. The UI being updated is just a RrogressBar that records the progress of the collection being filled up from THE LOOP that fills it up. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thank you. Id still like to know about caseType and the ProgressReport class.